# Xdebug triggered by Code Sniffer in PHPStorm

Tags: php, xdebug, phpcodesniffer

I have both xdebug and Code Sniffer working great on my installation of PHPStorm, but the one really annoying part is that the debugger now seems to be treating Code Sniffer errors as breakpoints and interrupts the code to let me know of style warnings while I'm trying to test out code.  What can I do to prevent Code Sniffer from being caught by the remote debugger in PHPStorm?

PS: I'm running Apache, using virtual hosts to map certain URLs to folders on my computer, and code sniffer never triggered PHPStorm's remote debugger explicitly, while my site caused PHPStorm to ask me if I wanted to include it's virtual URL for debugging.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it like this:
- went to "Project settings" -> "PHP" -> "Debug"
- under "XDebug" I unchecked the two "Force ..." options.

[image]

Hope it does the trick for you.

Answer (score -2):

I have added "-dxdebug.remote_enable=0" argument in last line of phpcs.bat and phpcbf.bat.

```
"%PHPBIN%" -dxdebug.remote_enable=0 "%~dp0\phpcbf" %*
```