# PhpStorm show CodeSniffer annoying message when install Xdebug

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, phpcodesniffer

After install Xdebug on **PhpStorm**, CodeSniffer start show this annoying balloon message:

> phpcs: Can not correctly run the tool with parameters:
>   /tmp/phpcs_temp.tmp/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php
>   --encoding=utf-8 --report=xml

**Environment:** PhpStorm 2017.1.2, Xdebug 2.5.3, CodeSniffer 3.0, Nginx

PS: I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528022/xdebug-triggered-by-code-sniffer-in-phpstorm), but it dose not help :(

Comment: are you trying to run controller with debugger?

Comment: this message I receive any time when use Xdebug, only is change is the name of the file

Comment: Is xdebug works well when you disabling CodeSniffer?

Comment: yes, all works fine, but this annoying message drive my crazy :)

Comment: have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201991/phpstorm-is-throwing-an-error-for-phpcs

Comment: thanks, this is must help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhpStorm Is throwing an error for phpcs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201991/phpstorm-is-throwing-an-error-for-phpcs)

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Slipknot suggested in the comments, the link [PhpStorm Is throwing an error for phpcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201991/phpstorm-is-throwing-an-error-for-phpcs) provide a working solution for me :

Under `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Quality tools` you can see which quality plugins are enabled (PHP CS or PHP MD). 
When you click on the "PHP CS Fixer Inspection" link (or on one of the other tools link here), you're redirected on the `editor > inspections` configuration in phpstorm. On this page, if you uncheck all the quality tools items (ie : PHP CS Fixer Validation), you should not have the problem anymore.

Hope it helps